# How to ensure serial semantics with Toast?

Tags: android, synchronization, toast

I was reviewing a student's program, which had code like this within an Activity:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
toast.setText("Goodbye");
```

This displayed the text "Goodbye", which was initially quite a surprise.  I assume this happened because the call to show() merely queues up a request to display the Toast instance and returns before it is actually displayed.  The call to setText("Goodbye") mutates the instance before it is displayed.

Two questions:

1. Is my interpretation correct?
2. What's the best way to ensure serial semantics in the presence of Toast mutation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt it's best to consult the source.

Toast internally uses a static reference to `INotificationManager` and calls it's [`enqueueToast`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java#l503) method every time a [`Toast.show()`](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/Toast.java#l96) is called.

It synchronizes around a List of Toasts so that only one Toast at a time is showed - this is needed if multiple Toast.show() are called then shows them one after another with their set duration.

Since Toasts references are enqueued (actually Toasts internal class TN is), calling `setText()` changes the enqueued Toast.

Comment: Good advice.  Any suggestions how to make sure the mutation doesn't happen until the Toast has been displayed?

Comment: You can't. Except if you make your own version of Toast.

Comment: How get to know that toast is now not showing. like in case of progress dialog .showing() method.